# How do I remove commas in an array in Angular project

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, text-processing

I am trying to call a list of actors from movies; in the DB I made, they all have commas at the end of each string.  When the array is called, the content displays with 2 commas after each other and I am wondering how I can get rid of that. I have tried to use .join but I don't know how to implement it into the HTML (I am new at Angular).

Here is the HTML and .ts files:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FetchApiDataService } from '../fetch-api-data.service'
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { GenreComponent } from '../genre/genre.component';
import { DirectorComponent } from '../director/director.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-card',
  templateUrl: './movie-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-card.component.css']
})
export class MovieCardComponent implements OnInit {
  movies: any[] = [];
  actors: any[] = [];
  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public fetchApiData: FetchApiDataService,
    public router:Router,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMovies();
  }

  removeCommas(): void {
    this.actors.join(' ');
  }

  getMovies(): void {
    this.fetchApiData.getAllMovies().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.movies = response;
      console.log(this.movies);
      return this.movies;
    });
  }

  openGenreDialog(genreName: string): void {
    this.dialog.open(GenreComponent, {
      width: '280px',
      data: {
        genreName: genreName
      }
    });
  }
  openDirectorDialog(directorName: string): void {
    this.dialog.open(DirectorComponent, {
      width: '280px',
      data: {
        directorName: directorName
      }
    });
  }

}




<div style="display: flex;">
    <mat-card *ngFor="let movie of movies;" style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
        <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{movie.Title}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>Starring: {{movie.Actors}}</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img src={{movie.ImagePath}} alt= {{movie.Title}} />
        <mat-card-actions>
            <button
                mat-button
                color="primary"
                (click)="openGenreDialog(movie.Genre.Name)"
            >
                Genre
            </button>
            <button
                mat-button
                color="primary"
                (click)="openDirectorDialog(movie.Director.Name)"
            >
                Director
            </button>
            <button
                mat-button
                color="primary"
            >
                Synopsis
            </button>
            <mat-icon>favorite_border</mat-icon>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Your actors are stored in the DB with commas?

Comment: Yea, I don't remember why I had it like that, I was a beginner   Here is an example (this was done in Mongo)   Actors
:
Array
0
:
"Will Ferrel, "
1
:
"John C. Reilly, "
2
:
"Sacha Baron Cohen"

Answer (score 0):

You can run the [map pipe](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method in your array.

```js
getMovies(): void {
    this.fetchApiData.getAllMovies().pipe(
        map((actor) => actor.replace(',', ''))).
        subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.movies = response;
            console.log(this.movies);
            return this.movies;
        });
}
```

Comment: I get this error:  actor.replace is not a function

Comment: His code assumes `getAllMovies` emits actor names one at a time. But I agree with the concept. make a `movieFixFunction` method that, given a `Movie`, fixes the actor string and returns the fixed `Movie`. Then replace his `map(...)` with `map(movies => movies.map(movie => this.movieFixFunction(movie)))`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will advice you to not use 'any' everywhere. It removes type checking and that can lead to issues and bugs in future.

As the returned object will be an Observable of type any[] (or Movies[] if you create a movie object with a string property named actor), you can do something like this. It will return an array of actors. For replace function, you will have to use a regexp expression to select all the commas in the value -

```
      getMovies() {
        this.fetchApiData
          .getAllMovies()
          .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
             this.movies = res;
             this.actors = res.map((movie: any) => movie.actor.replace(/,/g, ''));
             console.log(this.actors);
        });
      }
```

Comment: Same error message

Comment: Probably because of the 'any' keyword. Try adding a new Movie model with a property named actor in it and reference that as a type instead of any. That should resolve the issue. Movie model should look like the returned object from the api.